# Why the component is displayed twice?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am learning vue + vuex + vue-router. And I have a problem, certainly basic.

I have this app :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
        <home v-if="isLogged"></home>
        <login v-else></login>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The mechanism is OK . If I am connected, the component "home" is displayed else the component "login" is displayed. Perfect.

The component "home" is :

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png">
    
    HOME PAGE AVEC LES MENUS A FAIRE

    <router-link to="/user" v-if="isLogged">User</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about" v-if="isLogged">About</router-link>
    <button type="button" @click="logout()" v-if="isLogged">Logout</button>

    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

the router is :

```
    Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
        auth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    meta: {
      auth: true
    },
    component: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/user',
    name: 'User',
    meta: {
      auth: true
    },
    component: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/User.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "login" */ '../views/Login.vue')
  },
  { 
      path: '*', 
      component: () => import('../views/errors/NotFound.vue')
  }
]
```

I obtain this for the "/" route :

[image]

And this for the "about" route :

[image]

As you see the component "home " is displayed twice. And I do not understand why.

Comment: you have a `router-view` in home component, it should be on app.vue

Comment: thanks depprem for you answer. I already tried to move this "router-view" outside the "home" component. It is the same : component displayed twice.

Comment: VueRouter will replace `router-view` with component your provide in route definition so basically you just render `Home` component inside `Home` component. You should use `router-view` in app component as the above comment suggest.

Comment: I have understood. I removed the "Home" component from the router declaration, just commented the line *// component: Home*, and now it works like I wanted. I still continue to learn Vue. Thanks depprem and USer28

Answer (score 0):

1. Move your main router-view from Home component to App.vue.
2. Remove the Home component from App.vue, and add contemporary things like header and footer to App.vue, as they are gonna be layout of your App. The reason the component beingd displayed twice, is that create a Home component inside near another the same component, as it is already in layout. Your App.vue should look somehow like this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
        <AppHeader/>
        <router-view/>
        <AppFooter/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And Home.vue:

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main_content" v-if="isAuthenticated">
            <!-- Here goes you Home page -->
        </div>
        <login v-else></login>
    </div>
</template>
```

In your router.js just import the Home.vue and add new route:

```js
import Home from 'path/to/home.vue'
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home
    }
    // ... other routes
]
```